# How to conveniently evaluate a function at several points when there are way too many points

Tags: functions, function-construction, evaluation

Say I define a function as follows:

```
pos[n_] := If[Cos[288 ((n Pi)/233)] > 0 && Sin[288 ((n Pi)/233)] > 0, 1, 0]
```

Then I want to evaluate at this function at from $n=1$ to $n=233$. Okay so for now, I type it by hand...

```
pos /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
   19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
   36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52,
   53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
   70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86,
   87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 
  103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 
  116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 
  129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 
  142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 
  155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 
  168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 
  181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 
  194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 
  207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 
  220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 
  233}
```

This is really tiring, let along that I will evaluate from $n=1$ to $n=377$ in the next step. Is there a way for me to do this easier? I tried to evaluate as something like

```
pos/@{n,1<=n<=233}
```

but it didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: `Boole` is better than `If`, i.e., `pos[n_] := 
 Boole[Cos[288 ((n Pi)/233)] > 0 && Sin[288 ((n Pi)/233)] > 0]` Then `pos /@ Range[233]` or if instead you want to know the positions `Select[Range[233], pos[#] == 1 &]`

Comment: @BobHanlon oh nice. This gives what I want!!

Comment: @BobHanlon would you like to post an answer so that I can accept and people (and I) can upvote? :) I believe moving your comment to the answer will be great enough

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: @BobHanlon   okay. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As "BobHanlon" suggested, we can re-define the pos function as

```
pos[n_] := Boole[Cos[288 ((n Pi)/233)] > 0 && Sin[288 ((n Pi)/233)] > 0]
```

Then, if we want to evaluate from $n=1$ to $n=233$, we can use

```
pos /@ Range[233]
```

This will directly give us

```
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0}
```